# After updating wordpress 4.5 my homepage and images not displaying

Tags: updates, homepage

My site is http://exteriorinteriorsdesign.com/

After Updating wordpress 4.5,it  couldn't load my images and articles on Homepage, and dashboard also doesn't show when i move my cursor over there.

Any solution?

Comment: Everything is visible on your front page.

Answer (score 8):

You are using a theme or plugin that uses a jQuery-dependent script with poor syntax. In this screenshot below of the browser console of the page you referenced, the expression should be `... li > a[href*='#']`. Note the missing quotes around the #.

[image: Console screenshot of your site]

The bug didn't show up until now because WordPress 4.5 updated the version of jQuery it uses. The new jQuery version doesn't tolerate the bug. Ideally, your plugin/theme provider should issue a fix.

Until then, you can get the old version of jQuery back by adding the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpse_use_previous_jquery() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_use_previous_jquery' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. I was starting to get an eye headache.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that it's a PHP error related to your template or a plugin, but you'll need more info to solve it. First try disable all plugins and see if that makes a difference.

In order to see any errors that may be occurring, set your PHP `display_errors` directive to `On` if you have access, or you can try set the Debug constant in your Wordpress `wp-config.php` file to `true`. IE. `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

If it is a PHP error, the instructions above will help you get more info on what the error is and where it's occurring.