# Divi Theme - images not showing on front page

Tags: images, themes

I have been using the Divi theme for this site (http://www.evaecho.com) but all of a sudden without changing anything the images are not appearing on the front page (they are for all other pages).

There should be an image to the right of the text (it is there if you right click and 'open image in new tab') and below a fullwidth portfolio.

This has happened suddenly with no change in code.

Any advice massively appreciated.

Comment: Apparently Divi has a common jQuery problem that surfaced when updating to WordPress 4.5. See the [answer to this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223708/after-updating-wordpress-4-5-my-homepage-and-images-not-displaying/223713#223713)

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a javascript error in /js/custom.js

Look for the line: `$( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).click( function() {`

Change it to: `$( 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])' ).click( function() {`

You'll probably still have quirks with the page builder and various other functions until a theme update is released. Or, revert to the previous default version of jQuery.